# Custom Validator in Laravel Registration

Tags: laravel

I want to add a validation condition in the form to check if two string matches,
one string is variable to an external API, and the other is rand string generated for authentication,
`$externalstring==$randstring`  the $externalstring will be changed externally but how should the condition be implemented?

Comment: I'm not sure of my answer. If it's not the answer you waited for, can you be more specific and edit your question by adding some code snippets, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the validation rule you are looking for is `same`

According to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-same) :

You'll have to use it like this : `'externalString' => 'same:randString'`